# JPA -- Using the one-to-one dependency relationship on insertion

Tags: jpa, orm, annotations, dependencies

I have 2 entity classes with one-to-one dependencies on their primary keys:

The primary table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tablePrimary")
@XmlRootElement
//...  
public class TablePrimary implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "code")
private String code;

// set the dependency of table2 to this class
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Table2 table2inst;  

// ...
} // end of class TablePrimary
```

The dependent table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
@XmlRootElement
//...
public class Table2 implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@MapsId 
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "table2inst")   
@JoinColumn(name = "id")    
private TablePrimary tablePrimaryInst;

//...

}  // end of class Table2
```

Whenever there is a row with say, `id==55` in `TablePrimary`, there is 
a row with the same `id==55` in `Table2` and vice-versa. 
So in essence, these two tables are one table in logical level-- split into 2 physical tables for practicality.

When i'm inserting a row into the "logical" table, 
i first am inserting to `TablePrimary`-- the primary table in the relationship, 
getting the value of `id==55` field of this new row i just inserted and inserting a row to 
Table2 with that id value.
As part of this, i'm checking, just in case, 
whether a row with `id==55` is already in `Table2`.

Is there a better way of doing this?
Does JPA have a feature to make these two insertions to these two physical tables 
by using the 1-1 dependency I configured on them-- without me having to do it "manually" in the code? Or a control feature on the `id` fields of the tables I set the dependency on?
If there is-- how is done? how does it handle the key value collision in the dependent table-- `Table2`?

A similar thing will come up on deletion. However, i'm not there yet, and might figure out out of this.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of JPA cascading. You will have to define a cascade on the owning side (the one with the join column). If you have set the owning side of the relationship and persist the owning side, the inverse side will be persisted as well:

```
TablePrimary tp = new TablePrimary();
Table2 t2 = new Table2();
t2.setTablePrimaryInst(tp);
entityManager.persist(t2);
```

The 'mappedBy' element is supposed to be placed on the inverse side. You entities could look like this:

```
public class Table2 ...

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
@JoinColumn(name = "tp_id")    
private TablePrimary tablePrimary;

public class TablePrimary...

@OneToOne(mappedBy="tablePrimary")      
private Table2 table2;
```

Comment: the key field of my primary table is autogenerated and dependencies are on the key fields of the tables. when I run the insertion, I'm getting an exception saying that the key field of Table2 cannot be null.

Comment: why not use @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn as in my code? I heard there are some flaws on this annotation in some JPA providers, is that it?